# Why does this pattern matching code not work?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do some pattern matching in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) (\\.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("5 soy milk");
String qty = m.group(1);
String name = m.group(2);
```

I want to end up with one string that contains "5" and one string that contains "soy milk".  However, this pattern matching code gives me an IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `matches()` before you attempt to get the groups.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()

> `public boolean matches()`
>
> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
>   If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) (\\.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("5 soy milk");

if (m.matches())
{
  String qty = m.group(1);
  String name = m.group(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't initiate your `Matcher`. You should `p.matcher(...).matches()` (or `.find()`, or `.lookingAt()`, depending on the desired behaviour -- real regex matching is done with `.find()`).

And check the result of `.matches()` since in your case it returns *false*: `\.+` (`"\\.+"` in a Java string) will try and match *a dot* one or more times; you should use `.+` (`".+"` in a Java string) to match "any character, one or more times".